Stencil Components within a NextJs project
I created a stencil component library and I am trying to integrate it in a NextJs app. The components are loading and everything works fine. One problem tho:

I am on page /foo. I display one component
I am navigating to page /foo/{bar} from withing /foo. I display a second (different component) and it looks okay.
When I navigate back to /foo, the initial component has no styling. I've tried many many ways to force it to re-render or hydrate but to no avail.

Checking the Style Editor within Firefox, I see that the styles are loaded as such: first component > second component > and when back to first, they don't reload.
I have a very similar setup as the with-stencil example (of course, with more complex elements).
What could be the root cause?

Please validate the problem is not caused by Stencil, but adding a vanilla web component with a shadow root and an adopted stylesheet, and see if that works.

I'm not sure what framework is at fault. However, I found out that stencil works as expected if included in NextJs components that are full client-side (all components specify use client).
